# Mechanize gem V-2.7.2 with ruby 2.2.5 & Rails 5 returning the same url on submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mechanize

I am trying to do an authentication to a third party url using Mechanize gem. Find below my code,

```
 class ExternalAuth::HttpSession
  attr_accessor :session

  def initialize
   @session = Mechanize.new_with_proxy
   @req_res_array = []
  end
 end

 class Mechanize

  def self.new_with_proxy
  agent = MechanizeTimeoutProxy.new

  agent.set_proxy(PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT) if defined?(PROXY_HOST)

  agent
 end

end

 def initialize(vendor_credentials)
  logger.debug "Initialized with #{vendor_credentials.inspect}"

  @vendor_credentials = vendor_credentials
  @http = ExternalAuth::HttpSession.new

end
 #I am calling this method from my parent class

 def attempt_login(username, password)
  url = "http://sampleurl"
  vi  = "11"
  vt  = "1234567"
  full_url = "#{url}?vi=#{vi}&vt=#{vt}"
  logger.debug "Attempting login at #{full_url}"
  start = Time.now      
  page = @http.get full_url     
  form = page.form_with id: 'LoginForm'
  form['LoginTextBox'] = username
  form['PasswordTextBox'] = password     
  form.add_button_to_query form.button_with(name: 'SubmitButton')     
  page = form.submit        
  logger.info "SSO login form submitted in #{Time.now - start}"
  redirect_url = page.uri.to_s
  logger.debug "Redirect URL: #{redirect_url}"      
  encrypted_customer_token = (redirect_url[/\?ct=([^&]+)/] || '')[4..-1]
  logger.debug "encrypted_customer_token: #{encrypted_customer_token}"
  raise LoginFailedException if encrypted_customer_token.blank?  

  encrypted_customer_token
 end
```

Have provided here with only sample URL. form submit is returning the same URL in the redirect_url. Let me know what mistake has been done here.

Comment: What's `MechanizeTimeoutProxy`? It feels like you're being too fancy. Try to find a simpler way to do whatever you're doing.